# C++ calling destructors doesnt realy delete objects from memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, destructor

I am quite new in C++ and I am working on application, where I am alocating a lot of objects in memory by using `new` keyword like `MyObject* obj = new Object()` . After some operations with them (some lines of code later), I am calling destructors like `delete obj`. But after a lot of iterations i have noticed, that there is a huge consumption of memory and apparently these objects were not destroyed. So I tried simple example :

```
Algorhitm* alg;
for (int o = 0; o < 500000000; o++)
{
    alg = new Algorhitm();
    alg->~Algorhitm();
}
```

and also `delete alg`, but it seems like there is no memory dealocation. Memory comsumption increased to the critical point and then it caused breaking down my application. Could someone explain to me, what I am doing wrong? I used memory profilling tool called C++ Memory Validator, and in section with some charts of memory allocation and dealocation, theere was only allocation, but no dealocation recognized by this tool.

Comment: Is there a __good__ reason you're using dynamic memory in the first place ?

Comment: You're asking about **undefined behavior**!! The deallocated memory isn't really usable at all!

Comment: What members does class `Algorhitm` have? If it has any pointers, you must write your own destructor to free them. They are not "freed" by the default destructor. Also, typically you should stick to `delete` instead of manually calling the destructor.

Comment: Please give a [complete, minimal program](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the program. There are half a dozen fundamental things you might be doing wrong, and although there are good answers for each of them, we first need to find out which case we're dealing with.

Comment: @Chnosses he has a reason - a loop - maybe it will have dynamicaly set limit.

Comment: And as to the question - `delete` should be enough. Calling destructor explicitly has nothing to do with freeing memory.

Comment: Daniel's comment upvoted :) - good suggestion - maybe `Algorithm` class allocates some memory which is not made free in its destructor.

Comment: Could you post Algorithm class?

Comment: `alg->~Algorithm();` calls the destructor but it does not deallocate memory. You have to use `delete alg;` to deallocate memory.

Comment: @RSahu, And to be clear, `delete` deallocates memory *and* calls the destructor.

Comment: @rednaks If `Algorithm`'s destructor releases everything that its constructor allocates, then the net result of `delete new Algorithm();` should be zero, even when looking at fragmentation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, your claim that this is undefined behavior is wrong also.  It's a memory leak.  Using the memory remains allowable, but without a pointer to it, there's no way to do so.

Comment: @BenVoigt That might well be true (my first comment was just a shot in the dark)! But what rednaks said isn't matching the problem at all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **never** should call destructor functions using the `~<destructor>` function directly! You should just call

```
delete alg;
```

or rely on the destructor being called and allocated memory being released from going out of scope with a stack allocated instance of your class.

The direct call of the destructor function has no influence on the memory management at all, and is wrong in most cases (there are rare necessary with custom `delete` implementations).

This **will** free the memory allocated before.
Though you might see data structures remaining there. Accessing these after `delete`, leads  to undefined behavior in any case!

Answer (score 1):

I agree. Calling destructors doesn't really release memory, unless the destructor calls delete or free().

Calling delete or free() does however release memory, but back to the heap, not to the operating system.